# Which word describes 'keeping one's hand on another's shoulder'

Tags: single-word-requests

We know that friends generally walk by keeping one's hand on their friend's shoulders.

Is there any single word that has the same meaning as '**keeping one's hand on another's shoulder**?

Comment: You might be able to make "clasped" work  .

Comment: "Arms over shoulder" -- not a word, but works.  https://www.google.com/search?q=arms+over+shoulder&hl=en-IN&tbs=simg:CAESmQEJpkUdp8LS8sQajQELEKjU2AQaBgg-CEMIFQwLELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKOsf7R_1rEPAf6B_1qEPAQmhyKHPEfuCWAMO4vgTD_1L_10v_1i-FMPkvuSUaMEUvGIPT429J22b9yWR_1Pmly_1UGBxsv38oyV1rL0cS5lp25heRCZmRBeE8RUtxJaTSAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEiAFKbQw&tbm=isch&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeyN2O9afbAhXNfSsKHZ76BU0QpwUIHw&biw=1024&bih=606&dpr=1

Comment: Or, "Arms around each other"

Comment: None of the sighted communities I’m aware of habitually walk that way.

Comment: Do you mean walking with one hand on the nearer shoulder (eg walking on your friend's left with your right hand on his left shoulder) or with your arm around him (eg walking on your friend's left with your right hand on his right shoulder). The second would be more common in the US or UK but I wouldn't say that either was done 'generally'

Comment: @BoldBen I asked for the second one...

Comment: As in the answer below by swmcdonnell we would say "with my arm around him" but I still wouldn't say that it was 'generally' done. I the UK most men who are walking like that with a friend who is not a sexual partner are more or less drunk. Women tend not to do it at all.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there's no single word** that means keeping your hand one someone's shoulder.

> He walked with his hand on her shoulder.
>
> They walked with their arms around each other.

(Walking arm-in-arm implies arms linked at the elbows, not the shoulders)

More **informal**:

> They were hanging on each other as they walked down the street.
>
> They were hanging all over each other as they walked down the street.